# Advertising audiences - Marketing cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, facebook, suppressionlist, adwords

Can I send a suppression list to Facebook and Adwords in my journey? Every use case I've seen so far is about sending an ad on Facebook, but is it possible to create a Facebook custom audience from journey builder to then populate a suppression list in my display buys?

Answer (score 1):

Short Answer: No.

The journey builder ad activity does not allow you to use post a suppression list to your ads account. 
[image]

To do this, you would have to download the audience and exclude them directly for the 3rd party provider.

This is a example of how this would work with [Facebook](https://www.facebook.com/business/a/custom-audience-exclusions).

Comment: Ok thanks. If I were to create a new advertising audience from the journey builder activity, it will be then automatically populated / refreshed with users falling in this branch of the decision tree, and if I add this newly created advertising audience as an audience exclusion in my Facebook campaign, wouldn't it behave as a 60%-ish (because of the Facebook PII match rates) deterministic audience automatically refreshed, so a sort of suppression list?

Comment: I am not sure I understand.. why would you publish an audience and at the same time exclude the same audience?

Comment: For example removing people who open email but don't click (low interest) from my retargeting efforts on facebook to focus spend on other people, for increased marketing efficiency.

Comment: Got it. When you create that Audience, dont push it to Journey Builder. Create a second audience with the people you want to see it and use the first list as an exclusion criteria in FB

Comment: but if I don't push the first list to the journey builder how can I make sure it's automatically refreshed? I would like to avoid manual updates.
In my understanding I would define a branch in my decision tree to isolate people who opened but did not click and automatically populate the associated audience in Facebook added as an exclusion in my Facebook campaign

Comment: You can set up an automation in automation studio to refresh the audiences

Comment: true but what would be the benefit as opposed to adding this in the journey? update frequency?

Comment: If you add them to the journey to will send ads to them. If I understand your use case properly, you want do not want them receiving ads?

Comment: right, but the ads are necessarily managed from ET? I was under the impression that the campaign will be eventually listed in my facebook business manager account and the newly created audience available in FBM account as well, so it's just a matter of me setting up the right combinations of ads / exclusion from the ad platform